# php array or not array?

Tags: php, arrays

I don't understand... I'm doing something and when I do print_r($var); it tells me that I have an array, so naturally I think I have an array yet when I do

`if(is_array($xml->searchResult->item))`

it returns false

I use this array with foreach(); in documentation it says that foreach() won't work with anything else but array, so assuming that this is an array that I'm working...

plus, if I try to access it via 


`echo $xml->searchResult->item[3];`


i will get 4th element of my array

Answer (score 6):

print_r will also print objects as though they are arrays.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. XML nodes are objects.

Answer (score 3):

well, is_array() returns true if your variable is an array, otherwise, it returns false. In your case, $xml->searchResult->item seems not to be an array. What is the output for

```
var_dump($xml->searchResult->item)
```

? Another hint: You can determine the type of a variable via gettype().

Answer (score 1):

is_array() returns true only for real php arrays. It is possible to create a "fake" array by using the ArrayAccess class. That is, you can use normal array semantics (such as item[3]) but  it is not a real array. I suspect your $item is an object. So use

```
 if($x instanceof ArrayAccess || is_array($x))
```

Instead.

Comment: My understanding too.  That the result of the OP's reference can be used as an array in a very few ways, but not only will `is_array()` not be true, but many of the standard array functions like `array_merge()` will not work with it.

Answer (score 1):

> **plus, if I try to access it via echo $xml->searchResult->item[3]; i will get 4th element of my array**

That's right, the first element is always 0 unless you specifically change it.

Answer (score 0):

The manual does mention that `foreach` works on objects as well, and it will iterate over properties.

In your case, the situation is slightly different because I guess you're using SimpleXML, which is yet another special case. `SimpleXMLElement` has its own iterator, which I assume is hardcoded as it doesn't seem to implement any of [SPL](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)'s Iterator interfaces.

Long story short, some objects can be used *as* an array, but they *are not* one.

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful to check what has been returned by your array. You might have an object with class or stdClass which is empty and you cannot get element from it.